# Problem with url moving site from subdomain to main domain in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, migration, subdomain

Guys, I've a site that was moved from sub.domain.com to domain.com. To do this I used Backupbuddy plugin in Wordpress. The problem is..Everytime any user try to access to some old page url (domain.com/testpage) and the page doesn't exist, are being redirected to sub.domain.com/testpage where the page previously existed.

Any idea how to fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make change in your .htaccess file in your server or host. always redirects are in that file. if you are using cpanel you have to make visible hidden items in settings.

Comment: Sure mate, but I'm stuck there. The new site permalinks are (https)site.com/pagename and keeps redirect to (http)sub.site.com/?page_id=2
The site's working fine, the problem are all the missing page from the main site that keeps redirecting to the same page sub.site.com/?page_id=2

Answer (score 0):

I think the first port of call would be to check the URL in Wordpress matches the database table URL, if so update the Permalinks and retest.

Comment: Hi. Yeap, I gave it a look to the wp option table in database and its the same for the site. I tried to change the permalinks with the same estructure of the redirected link and the new site shows 404. Thanks :)

Comment: Revert and try a Search & Replace plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ (ensure you have sufficient backup).

Comment: I tried that yesterday. ;) In my database there's no sign of oldsubdomain.domain.com my friend

Answer (score 0):

Zip .htaccess to make a backup and remove the .htaccess file. Then, save your permalink again to generate a new .htaccess and check.